# Using Current Date - 7 days in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I am trying to insert a set of values when those values were entered in the last week.

When I use this

```
INSERT INTO myTable1 (acct#, name,location,...)
  SELECT acct#,name,location,...
  FROM myTable2
  WHERE acct#=acct# and entDate >=(CURRENT DATE -1 DAY)

INSERT INTO myTable1 (acct#, name,location,...)
  SELECT acct#,name,location,...
  FROM myTable2
  WHERE acct#=acct# and entDate >=(CURRENT DATE -1 DAY)
```

I get all the data from yesterday which is what I want, but when I replace

```
entDate >=(CURRENT DATE -1 DAY)
```

with

```
entDate >=(CURRENT DATE -7 DAYS)
```

I get an error that says "Character in CAST argument is not valid.

I'm not sure why this small change is throwing this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of `endDate`? Is it DATE?

Comment: How were the tables created? via DDS? If so, then they could contain bad data in any field. Also, I don't think the issue is with the date field, but potentially one of the records that is brought back by `current date - 7 days` has bad data that isn't in the data set returned by `current date - 1 day`.

Comment: Also, check the definitions of the fields being selected and the target columns. Are they exactly the same? The error should tell you which field is causing the problem, look in the job log.

Comment: The Data Type is Date.  I can get the Insert to work if I use a date range ie. endDate >=2019-8-12 and endDate <=2019-8-26.

Comment: I notice that your where clause contains `acct#=acct#` without any qualification as to whether you mean `myTable1` or `myTable2`.  This can certainly cause strange behavior like you are seeing.

Comment: You are right.  This was just quickly thrown together pseudocode.  In the real statement the field names aren't the same and are qualified.

Comment: My guess would be that data types in `myTable2` do not match exactly those in `myTable1`, e.g. some column is `VARCHAR` in the former but numeric or `DATE` in the latter, and implicit cast fails when data in the wider range of `endDate` cannot be converted.

Comment: How about another experiment?  Can you run the `select` query without the `insert`?  Does that still throw an error or does it return the correct results?  If that returns the right results, then it has to have something to do with the data types in the select vs the insert.

Comment: @Priide so you can get the insert to work when you do not include a row with bad data. My point is that you have bad data somewhere in your source file. It is not the SQL syntax that is the problem, but the bad data in the source table which cannot be cast into the destination column. It is your job to find that bad data.

Answer (score -1):

You use Day not Days.

```
$ db2 "select CURRENT DATE -1 DAY from sysibm.sysdummy1"

1
----------
08/25/2019

1 record(s) selected.


$ db2 "select CURRENT DATE -7 DAY from sysibm.sysdummy1"

1
----------
08/19/2019

1 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: Changing it to Day returns the same "Character in CAST argument is not valid." error.

Comment: DAYS is a perfectly valid and expected use: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzdtdur.htm